# plot surface of cusp catastrophe (with gnuplot)

Tags: plot, gnuplot, cusp

Is it possible to plot the surface of the [Cusp Catastrophe](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catastrophe_theory#Cusp_catastrophe) with Gnuplot? Here's a [comparable plot](http://ars.els-cdn.com/content/image/1-s2.0-S0925527398001807-gr1.jpg).

- The catastrophe is mathematically described by: V = x^4 + a*x^2 + b*x (Wikipedia, see above)
- The surface is describes by: 0 = a + b*y – y^3

I'm a gnu plot beginner, so I'd be really grateful for an example with source code.

(I study psychology and I need this plot for an essay about a clinical theory: the cusp catastrophe is used to describe changes of mood, that seem to appear more sudden and disruptive for depressive patients, compared to healthy persons.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the best way would be to generate a table of roots of the equation (outside of gnuplot) and then plot the table with splot. But you can get an approximation to what you want in gnuplot by trying

```
a=b=1
set para
set iso 30
set pm3d at s
set urange [-10:10]
set hidd
set view 47,192
splot a + u*v - b * v**3, u, v
```

Comment: I had no idea that gnuplot supported multiple assignment.  Neat