# How can I plot hysteresis in matplotlib?

Tags: python, matplotlib, mplot3d

I am trying to plot a the development of a pitchfork bifurcation over time. The relationship between *x* and *y* starts off approximately linear, but ends up being a sigmoidal <kbd>S</kbd> shape. The final relationship is not a function; there are multiple *y* values for some values of *x*.

Matplotlib does nice wire frames for surface plots, but these surface plots don't seem to be able to handle non-functions.
Is there another way of plotting just the surface of this relationship? (If possible I don't want a solid shape.)

At the moment my data is in zero arrays where `1`s indicate an approximation to the location of the surface. 
I've included a very small sample data set, and sample code that will plot of their location. How do I 'join the dots'?
My actual data sets are larger (500x200x200) and varied, so I need to develop a flexible system.

This is what the final figure might look like:

[image: pitchfork bifurcation]

From [reading `mplot3d` documentation here](http://matplotlib.org/mpl_toolkits/mplot3d/tutorial.html) it seems that I may need to convert my data to 2D arrays. 
If this is the case please could you provide a method for this, and if possible please tell me what these arrays represent.

I greatly appreciate any comment/suggestions that will advance this.

```
import numpy as np
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

sample_data = np.array([
[[ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
 [ 1.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
 [ 0.,  1.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
 [ 0.,  0.,  1.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
 [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  1.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
 [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  1.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
 [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  1.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
 [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  1.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
 [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  1.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
 [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  1.,  0.,  0.],
 [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  1.,  1.]],
[[ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
 [ 1.,  1.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
 [ 0.,  0.,  1.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
 [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
 [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  1.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
 [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  1.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
 [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  1.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
 [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  1.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
 [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  1.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
 [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  1.,  0.,  0.],
 [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  1.,  1.]],
[[ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
 [ 1.,  1.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
 [ 0.,  0.,  1.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
 [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  1.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
 [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
 [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  1.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
 [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  1.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
 [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  1.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
 [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  1.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
 [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  1.,  0.,  0.],
 [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  1.,  1.]],
[[ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
 [ 1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
 [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  1.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
 [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  1.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
 [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  1.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
 [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  1.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
 [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  1.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
 [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  1.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
 [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  1.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
 [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  1.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
 [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.]],
[[ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
 [ 1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
 [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  1.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
 [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  1.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
 [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  1.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
 [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
 [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  1.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
 [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  1.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
 [ 0.,  0.,  1.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
 [ 0.,  0.,  1.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
 [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.]],
[[ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
 [ 1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
 [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  1.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
 [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  1.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
 [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  1.,  1.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
 [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  1.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
 [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  1.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
 [ 0.,  1.,  1.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
 [ 1.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
 [ 1.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
 [ 0.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.]]
 ] )


XS, YS, ZS = [],[],[]
for g in xrange(np.shape(sample_data)[0]):
    for row in xrange(np.shape(sample_data)[1]):
        for col in xrange(np.shape(sample_data)[2]):
            if sample_data[g][row][col] == 1:
                XS.append(g)
                YS.append(col)
                ZS.append(row)
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')
ax.scatter(XS, YS, ZS)
plt.show()
```

[image: scatter]

Comment: If you really want 3D, use mayavi which is opengl backed.

Comment: Maybe you could generate a file with [x, y , z] coordinates and plot it with Mayavi2. In Python have you tried with a 3D Scatter Plot?

Comment: This can be helpful http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20702236/plotting-multivalued-surface-in-mayavi , which points to this http://docs.enthought.com/mayavi/mayavi/auto/example_surface_from_irregular_data.html#example-surface-from-irregular-data :)

Comment: @Daniel Power, need the same tool. If you manage to do the hysteresis plot please write a short report...

Comment: This says it's possible in gnuplot (specific to a cusp catastrophe, too): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13330446/plot-surface-of-cusp-catastrophe-with-gnuplot

Comment: and examples in Mathematica, Sage, pstricks (!), and a reference to R here: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/168928/plot-the-cusp-catastrophe-surface.    Do you specifically need matplotlib?

Comment: See below, @VitalyIsaev - maybe you can clean up the sprues.

Answer (score 2):

As suggested by mrcl, to do this in matplotlib you can use `trisurf`.
However, you have to provide your own triangles as Delaunay won't work on the 2d projection of your points.

To build the triangulation, I suggest to build a parametric representation of your surfece (in terms of *s*, *t*) and triangulate in the space *(s, t)*.

It will give something like this

[image]

Exemple based on your code below (as your data is very coarse, I added a bit of interpolation):

```
import numpy as np
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.tri as mtri
from matplotlib import cm

sample_data = np.array([
[[ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
 [ 1.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
 [ 0.,  1.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
 [ 0.,  0.,  1.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
 [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  1.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
 [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  1.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
 [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  1.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
 [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  1.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
 [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  1.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
 [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  1.,  0.,  0.],
 [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  1.,  1.]],
[[ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
 [ 1.,  1.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
 [ 0.,  0.,  1.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
 [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
 [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  1.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
 [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  1.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
 [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  1.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
 [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  1.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
 [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  1.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
 [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  1.,  0.,  0.],
 [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  1.,  1.]],
[[ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
 [ 1.,  1.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
 [ 0.,  0.,  1.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
 [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  1.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
 [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
 [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  1.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
 [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  1.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
 [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  1.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
 [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  1.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
 [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  1.,  0.,  0.],
 [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  1.,  1.]],
[[ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
 [ 1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
 [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  1.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
 [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  1.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
 [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  1.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
 [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  1.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
 [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  1.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
 [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  1.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
 [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  1.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
 [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  1.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
 [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.]],
[[ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
 [ 1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
 [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  1.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
 [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  1.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
 [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  1.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
 [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
 [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  1.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
 [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  1.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
 [ 0.,  0.,  1.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
 [ 0.,  0.,  1.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
 [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.]],
[[ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
 [ 1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
 [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  1.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
 [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  1.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
 [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  1.,  1.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
 [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  1.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
 [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  1.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
 [ 0.,  1.,  1.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
 [ 1.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
 [ 1.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
 [ 0.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.]]
 ] )


XS, YS, ZS = [],[],[]
for g in xrange(np.shape(sample_data)[0]):
    for row in xrange(np.shape(sample_data)[1]):
        for col in xrange(np.shape(sample_data)[2]):
            if sample_data[g][row][col] == 1:
                XS.append(g)
                YS.append(col)
                ZS.append(row)
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')
ax.scatter(XS, YS, ZS)
XS = np.asarray(XS)
YS = np.asarray(YS)
ZS = np.asarray(ZS)


def re_ordinate(x, y):
    ord = np.arange(np.shape(x)[0])
    iter = True
    itermax = 10
    n_iter = 0
    while iter and n_iter < itermax:
        n_iter += 1
        dist1 = (x[0:-2] - x[1:-1])**2 + (y[0:-2] - y[1:-1])**2
        dist2 = (x[0:-2] - x[2:])**2 + (y[0:-2] - y[2:])**2
        swap = np.argwhere(dist2 < dist1)
        for s in swap:
            s += 1
            t = x[s]
            x[s] = x[s+1]
            x[s+1] = t
            t = y[s]
            y[s] = y[s+1]
            y[s+1] = t
            t = ord[s]
            ord[s] = ord[s+1]
            ord[s+1] = t
    return ord / float(np.size(ord, 0))

# Building parametrisation of the surface
s = np.zeros(np.shape(XS)[0])
t = np.zeros(np.shape(XS)[0])
begin = 0
end = 0
for g in xrange(np.shape(sample_data)[0]):
    cut = np.argwhere(XS==g).flatten()
    begin = end
    end += np.size(cut, 0)
    X_loc = XS[cut]
    Y_loc = YS[cut]
    Z_loc = ZS[cut]
    s[begin: end] = g / float(np.size(sample_data, 0))
    t[begin: end] = re_ordinate(Y_loc, Z_loc)
    #ax.plot(X_loc, Y_loc, Z_loc, color="grey")

triangles = mtri.Triangulation(s, t).triangles
refiner = mtri.UniformTriRefiner(mtri.Triangulation(s, t))

subdiv = 2
_, x_refi = refiner.refine_field(XS, subdiv=subdiv)
_, y_refi = refiner.refine_field(YS, subdiv=subdiv)
triang_param, z_refi = refiner.refine_field(ZS, subdiv=subdiv)

#triang_param = refiner.refine_triangulation()#mtri.Triangulation(XS, YS, triangles)
#print triang_param.triangles
triang = mtri.Triangulation(x_refi, y_refi, triang_param.triangles)
ax.plot_trisurf(triang, z_refi,  cmap=cm.jet, lw=0.)


plt.show()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
ax.plot_trisurf(XS, YS, ZS)
```

instead of

```
ax.scartter(XS, YS, ZS)
```

But as **tcaswell** has commented, mayavi will give you better performance.

Cheers

Comment: `plot_trisurf` wouldn't triangulate the cusp, either; I got the warning "matplotlib/delaunay/triangulate.py:104: DuplicatePointWarning: Input data contains duplicate x,y points; some values are ignored." Shuffling the X, Y, Z orientation won't work for all cases either (including this one, AFAICT).